# C#, selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to create a variable webdriver that i can call in all of my tests. 
I currently have the following example for display purposes.

Here I define my webdriver I want to use:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;

namespace WebAuto
{
    public class OpenBrowser
    {
        private static IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        public IWebDriver getDriver()
        {
            return driver;
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to call this webdriver in another Test called Login:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;


namespace WebAuto
{
    public class Login 
    { 
        public static void Login1() 
    {
            //var driver = new ChromeDriver();
            OpenBrowser.IWebDriver. getDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.anywebsite.com");
            //driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.anywebsite.com");
            //driver.WaitForPageToLoad();
            var inputtext1 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("lgLogin_txtUserId"));
            //inputtext1.Focus();
            inputtext1.SendKeys("User");
            var inputpassword1 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("lgLogin_txtPassword"));
            //inputpassword1.Focus();
            inputpassword1.SendKeys("Password");
            var inputbutton1 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnLoginClient"));
            inputbutton1.Click();
            //driver.WaitForPageToLoad();

        }

    }
}
```

Could someone please explain what I am missing????

Comment: Hey, @hthomas. Would you be able to share the error message you are seeing with us? Does the program compile? Or does it execute, but do the wrong thing?

Answer (score 3):

The way to call the `driver` from `Login` class is

```
OpenBrowser openBrowser = new OpenBrowser();
IWebDriver driver = openBrowser.getDriver();
```

Comment: This is correct but he should probably just make the `OpenBrowser` class `static`.