# Open chrome and Auto fill the form fields windows form C#

Tags: c#

I want to Open chrome and Auto fill the form fields windows form C#.
    automatically open a new google chrome web browser to a predefined URL 
    automatically complete required fields with predefined data
    I don't want to open web within Form control WebBrowser.

If I try the below code it's not working.

```
        System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
    HtmlDocument document = null;
    document=webBrowser.Document;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.co.in");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#, selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046140/c-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Please check out selenium or other browser automation. This is way too broad a question.

Comment: if you can change web server, one of the cheap solution is: change parameters of your destination url, like aaa/someform?a=x&b=xx..., then navigate to the url directly. but if you cannot change web server, you will have to learn how to use socket to communicate with Chrome, it's totally different with Forms.WebBrowser

Comment: I cannot do with query string parameters. The website source is not in my hand. I want to open new standalone Chrome browser with a specific URL and Auto fill form. I don't want to use Windows form control in my Form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the approach you have already started (without opening chrome and using the `WebBrowser` control) :

```
   System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
    webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e)=>{
     //add auto fill here ie:
     HtmlDocument doc = ((WebBrwoser)s).Document;
     var element = doc.GetElementById("email");
if(element!=null) element.SetAttribute("value", "AutoFillValue");
};
    webBrowser.Navigate(someUrl);
```

If you insist on using Chrome, you should use [Chrome WebDrive](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2013/01/18/selenium-webdriver-using-chrome-webdriver-in-visual-studio-c/)

Answer (score 0):

if you know the form field names, they can be prefilled by passing them as query string parameters

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.co.in?q=test");
```

Comment: No I cannot do with query string parameters. I want to Auto Fill the data in web form. I can access only the URL only,

Comment: adding the correct query string parameters will populate the fields of the web form